# Jersey unable to unmarshal object with MOXy (Content is not allowed in prolog)

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey, moxy

I have the following method implemented using JAX-RS 2.0 (Jersey):

```
@PUT
@Path("container/{containername}/catalog")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response updateCatalog(@PathParam("containername") String containerName, 
        @FormDataParam("catalog") SIRFCatalog catalog) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    log.info("Unmarshalling config...");
    SIRFConfiguration config = new SIRFConfigurationUnmarshaller().
            unmarshalConfig(new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(
            SIRFConfiguration.SIRF_DEFAULT_DIRECTORY + "conf.json"))));
    log.info("Creating strategy...");
    StorageContainerStrategy strat = AbstractStrategyFactory.createStrategy(config);
    log.info("Pushing catalog...");
    strat.pushCatalog(catalog, containerName);

    log.info("Sending response...");
    return Response.ok(new URI("sirf/container/" + containerName + "/catalog")).build();
}
```

I am using Eclipse MOXy and the War file has the `jaxb.properties` file in the same directory as the compiled class. The contents of the properties file are:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

When I sent an XML file containing a `SIRFCatalog` everything runs as expected:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" -F catalog=@a.xml http://$OPENSIRF_IP:$OPENSIRF_PORT/sirf/container/philContainer/catalog
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 48
Date: Sat, 10 Sep 2016 18:30:30 GMT

{"value":"sirf/container/philContainer/catalog"}
```

However, when I send the very same contents in JSON (and I know they are the same because I marshalled the same object to XML and JSON and saved to `a.xml` and `a.json`) I get an HTTP 400:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" -F catalog=@a.json http://$OPENSIRF_IP:$OPENSIRF_PORT/sirf/container/philContainer/catalog
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 1033
Date: Sat, 10 Sep 2016 18:30:38 GMT
Connection: close

<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/8.0.36 - Error report</title><style type="text/css">H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}.line {height: 1px; background-color: #525D76; border: none;}</style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request</h1><div class="line"></div><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Bad Request</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.</u></p><hr class="line"><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.36</h3></body></html>
```

I suspect that my server is actually using Vanilla JAXB instead of MOXy, but have no idea how to debug that! The tomcat8 logs say `Content not allowed in prolog`:

```
10-Sep-2016 18:30:36.902 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-21] org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter.log 2 * Server has received a request on thread http-nio-8080-exec-21
2 > PUT http://200.144.189.109:8088/sirf/container/philContainer/catalog
2 > accept: */*
2 > content-length: 1755
2 > content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------bb3a9e312931
2 > expect: 100-continue
2 > host: 200.144.189.109:8088
2 > user-agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.19.1 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2

[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
10-Sep-2016 18:30:38.386 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-21] org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter.log 2 * Server responded with a response on thread http-nio-8080-exec-21
2 < 400
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, when I send the very same contents in JSON (and I know they
>   are the same because I marshalled the same object to XML and JSON and
>   saved to a.xml and a.json) I get an HTTP 400:

I suspect the generated `json` has root `node` (like in `XML`) and so you will have to instruct `MOxy` to not use root node. Please check this [link](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/03/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html) and [link](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html) as explained by Blaise.

UPDATE:
And yes you will need to specify the type of data in the cURL command as below:

```
-F "catalog=@a.json;type=application/json"
```

Comment: I added `MOXyJsonProvider` to a new `Application` and loaded it on startup from `web.xml` (I wrote to the log during the class loading and confirmed that the servlet is run when tomcat starts). Still same symptom :(

Comment: see update. also check if your `json` has root node and remove it.

Comment: My json file doesn't have a root node. Adding the type of that particular parameter helped getting through the `HTTP 400`, so thank you for that! :) however, the `catalog` object is `null` in the `updateCatalog()` method... :(

Comment: the reason why I was getting `HTTP 400` was due to your cURL syntax. like you did above I get HTTP 400, but if I change it to `-F "catalog=@a.json;type=application/json"` it works fine (see the difference in the double quotes). I changed your answer so I could accept it.